# Is my estimated limit for diffracting tiny animals reasonable?

Tags: diffraction, estimation

In ["How small could an animal be before it is affected by quantum mechanics?"](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/60328/how-small-could-an-animal-be-before-it-is-affected-by-quantum-mechanics/60457#60457) on worldbuilding.stackexchange I did a quick and dirty estimate of how big an animal could be and still experience de Broglie matter diffraction. I derived the limit essentially by increasing the size of the aggregate particle from zero until it exceeds the size of the diffraction grating, given assumptions about density and velocity.

> $mv=\frac{h}{\lambda}$ and as a coarse simplification, since we're dealing with small animals, pick $v=1ms^{-1}$ so $m=\frac{h}{\lambda}$.
>
> Model the "particle" animal as a uniform sphere of "typical" density of $\rho\approx 10 kg\cdot m^{-3}$ so $m=\frac{4}{3}\rho\pi r^3\approx 4\rho r^3$ and as we said above, we are looking for $r=\lambda$ so $\frac{h}{r}\approx 4 \rho r^3$ and so...
>
> $r \approx 2\times 10^{-9}m$

As far as rough estimates go, is my method reasonable? Are there wildly inappropriate assumptions in there, or mathematical facepalms? Or is it basically okay?

Comment: NB $\rho=1$ (water) might be an obvious guess, but my model of a tiny animal is one which would be built differently, so I went with the  middle density over elements. In case you're curious.

Comment: This seems to be a "check my work" type of question.

Answer (score 0):

> I did a quick and dirty estimate of how big an animal could be and still experience de Broglie matter diffraction.

A virus is not an animal, but lets not quibble about about that. If I understand you correctly, matter diffraction of an animal would result in a diffraction pattern. If I have this understanding wrong, my apologies.

The largest object to exhibit interference patterns in recent experiments is a molecule comprised of about 100 atoms.

[image]

Image Source: [Width of Biological Objects](http://book.bionumbers.org/size-and-geometry-introduction/)

So categorizing the virus as a animal, far wider than 100 atoms,  even any virus has no chance of being diffracted. There is no animal small enough to undergo the diffraction process.

Again, if I misunderstood your assumptions and your argument, my apologies and I will delete this post.

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to happen with animals, Schroedinger's cat aside. Diffraction experiments have been done with buckminsterfullerines. In particular the $C_{60}$ carbon "soccer ball" has been [studied](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/1999/oct/15/wave-particle-duality-seen-in-carbon-60-molecules) as a large quantum system.  The $C_{60}$ is a nanometer with a de Broglie wave length $2.5\times 10^{-9}cm$. Which is much smaller. A back of the envelope calculation based on scaling tells me that a virion particle of $10^{-5} cm$ would have a wavelength at about $10^{-15}cm$. This will be very difficult to perform an experiment on.

It might be possible to entangle two virions. Suppose you have two supercooled virions particles, where these absorb a photon in an entangled state. You might then be able to get some quantization with respect to entangled virion particles. People doing these experiments keep pushing the barriers so that what seems impossible today become real tomorrow.

Comment: So $C_{60}$ is about the same size as my estimate, right? Your viron is wider than the gap it would diffract through, so wouldn't it just smash against the walls?